# JRE fatal error while tomcat restart (caught unhandled signal 11) on customized Arch Linux ARM

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I am relatively new to tomcat and facing this problem. I am using customized Arch Linux ARM on raspberry pi. Whenever I run startup.sh, I get this output in Catalina.out and tomcat doesn't start.
Please help

```
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9090
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:09 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 10668 ms
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Dec 12, 2013 6:02:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_linux_zero.cpp:285), pid=228, tid=3062170736
#  fatal error: caught unhandled signal 11
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK Zero VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.3.9
# Distribution: Custom build (Mon Sep 23 22:52:25 CDT 2013)
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/tomcat/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/core or core.228
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/tomcat/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/hs_err_pid228.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
```

Comment: it's maybe some  file corruption in the JVM. You can try upgrade to latest version.

Comment: This could be due to a bug in your JVM, or one of the shared libraries in uses. Signal 11 is `SIGSEGV`, which indicates that the (C++) code of the JVM tried to dereference an invalid pointer (probably a NULL pointer).

Comment: Check the /opt/tomcat/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/hs_err_pid228.log file it will list all the native libraries that were loaded and will help point what is going on. This could be due to a build with a different native library version than your system's. Try to run a simpler Java program and see what happens. Also, if you could post the result of the log file it could help.

Comment: thanks all for your prompt reply